# Accept Swedish letters (åäö) in Postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding

I can't find information about how to accept Swedish letters (åäö) in a PSQL table. I've tried this: https://tech.willandskill.se/create-a-database-with-different-encoding/

but i'm getting an error in my terminal that says:

```
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "sv_SE.UTF-8"
```

when I tried this:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name ENCODING 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE 'sv_SE.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'sv_SE.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0;
```

Is there a way to accept those letters in my database? 
I appreciate all help.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Postgres uses the collation available in the operating system.

Comment: macOS Mojave @a_horse_with_no_name